# Discrete time LTI system's unit impulse response equation

Tags: signal

Hello i have got a question which i could not find an answer below:

A discrete time LTI system's unit impulse response is :
$$ℎ[] =\dfrac{1}{5}([] + [ − 1] + [ − 2] + [ − 3] + [ − 4])$$ so how can i find response signal y[n] for $$x[n]=(\dfrac{1}{2})^nu[n]$$

Comment: Discrete convolution: fold; slide; multiply; add.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try.